# Postgresql: backup all table structures but only a few data table

Tags: postgresql, database-backups, pg-dump

I have a database with some tables for the application settings, lists like users, departments, cities. I want the structure and the data for those tables. So if i get a new user the backup will save it.

But also have some data for historic and calculated data, that data came from another sources and only work for some time and then expire, so backup that data will be a waste. But will need have the structure so the restore will create the tables need it for the application.

right now I'm using this command but this save all table and all data.

```
pg_dump -U "postgres" -h "local" -p "5432" 
        -d dbName -F c -b -v -f c:\uti\backup.dmp
```

I have 2 additional questions regarding pg_dump.

A) docs say option -b is for blob data. I have very big tables, but i guess this options is for only tables with a BLOB field, so shouldn't make any difference in my backup because i don't have those fields ?.

B) I see pg_dump options are for tables and schemas. How you specify if want save the functions code?

Comment: Do it in 2 steps. Backup your schema (with functions) and then selectively table data.

Comment: So i made a pg_dump to a file `backup` ... and then another pg_dump to the same file? If that is the case, just submit it as answer so i can vote for it.

Comment: ok, that doesn't work because overwrite first file.

Comment: re a): `-b` is for large objects, not for `bytea` columns (Postgres' equivalent to a `BLOB` is `bytea`)

Comment: so what are large object? table with lot of rows?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza (for future sake) you can use `--blobs` to include blob objects in dumps.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Exclude the tables you do not want to backup

```
pg_dump -U "postgres" -h "local" -p "5432" 
        -d dbName -F c -b -v -f c:\uti\backup.dmp
        --exclude-table-data '*.table_name_pattern_*'
        --exclude-table-data 'some_schema.another_*_pattern_*'
```

The function creation code is part of the schema.

Comment: So even i exclude the table the `CREATE TABLE` statement still will be in the backup? Also ... looks like i can put multiple `--exclude-table-data` parameter?

Comment: Yes it only excludes the table data. The table creation statement will be output to the backup. Yes multiple `--exclude-table-data`

Comment: older than 9.2 has to do this in two steps:
The first step is to backup database schema
      `pg_dump --schema-only`
The second step is to backup table data excluding certain table
      `pg_dump --data-only --exclude-table`

Answer (score 0):

Clodoaldo Neto's is the way to go. However, I witnessed a strange behavior when using `pg_dump` with capital letters. The issue is also described [here](https://postgrespro.ru/list/thread-id/2502011)

So in my case the table to ignore was named `ChangeHistory` and the trick to ignore it was wildcarding capital letters as below

```
pg_dump [omitted for brievity] --exclude-table "*hange*istory"
```

Comment: try this --exclude-table '\*.\"ChangeHistory\"""'